# How to open Phonegap iOS application using url in email for password reset

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I have created an iOS application using Phonegap. I want to implement reset password functionality. When user selects 'forgot password', application sends a link to reset the password on his registered email. Using that link user can update a password from web browser.

I want to open my Phonegap application when user clicks on link which he received in his email.

The link is like: https://mydomainReset.com/reset

1. Can I launch my application using URL scheme of iOS? i.e. can I set "https://mydomainReset.com" in "URL types"->"URL Schemes" in Info.plist of the application.

If no is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can do it as you've suggested

Comment: If I specify "https://testURL.com" in URL Schemes and tried to open app from safari using "https://testURL.com://" it down't open the application. But If I set "myTestApp"  in URL Schemes and tried to open app from safari using "myTestApp://" it open the my application. How do I solve it?

Comment: what you might have to do is to have your testURL.com probably redirect to myTestApp:// . this should then launch your app. Its a bit ugly but it should work.

Comment: I know using "myTestApp://" application get launched. I just want to know if url is like "https:// testURL.com", How to launch the application.

Comment: that's what I said before, the testURL.com *will have to redirect to* myTestApp://. The problem is that using testURL.com will get the system to identify it as a website address rather than a custom URI scheme. Hence it will open the device browser. To get around this, you need the redirect as mentioned to the actual URI scheme myTestApp://